# OPENSSH - authentication issue with keys ( Permission denied (publickey) )

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sshd

I try to run an SSH Server with **openSSH** and configure a passwordless user for ssh tunneling

```
root@kali:~/myssh# ssh -V  
OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

I already testing SSH Server on **raspberry** and **CENTOS VPS** and I got an error like below

```
tunnel@192.168.1.99: Permission denied (publickey).
```

my ssh server has a user ' **tunnel** ' without a password and I generate RSA keys ( without the passphrase ) with **ssh-keygen** for this user and also an HostKey File

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/myssh/tunnel/id_rsa -P ""
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/myssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

and Here is my **custon_config.conf** ( ~/myssh/custon_config.conf )

```
Protocol 2
ListenAddress 192.168.1.99
HostKey  /root/myssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Port 2222
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256

MACs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1


PermitRootLogin no
AuthorizedKeysFile /root/myssh/tunnel/id_rsa
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

I run my ssh server using this command

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /root/myssh/tunnel_ssh.conf && while true;do sleep 30; done;
```

and try to connect it on my pc like this

```
ssh tunnel@192.168.1.99 -p 2222 -i /mykeys/id_rsa
```

the **id_rsa** file is the **tunnel** user RSA key that generated on Server

Now I don't know what's wrong with my keys and permissions also I try the .pub key and it didn't work.
I'll appreciate that if somebody helps me to fix this

UPDATE

I try to regenerate the keys for tunnel user and try to connect with `-vvv`

I try to run an SSH Server with **openSSH** and configure a passwordless user for ssh tunneling

```
root@kali:~/myssh# ssh -V  
OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

I already testing SSH Server on **raspberry** and **CENTOS VPS** and I got an error like below

```
tunnel@192.168.1.99: Permission denied (publickey).
```

my ssh server has a user ' **tunnel** ' without a password and I generate RSA keys ( without the passphrase ) with **ssh-keygen** for this user and also an HostKey File

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/myssh/tunnel/id_rsa -P ""
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/myssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

and Here is my **custon_config.conf** ( ~/myssh/custon_config.conf )

```
Protocol 2
ListenAddress 192.168.1.99
HostKey  /root/myssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Port 2222
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com

KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256

MACs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1


PermitRootLogin no
AuthorizedKeysFile /root/myssh/tunnel/id_rsa
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

I run my ssh server using this command

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /root/myssh/tunnel_ssh.conf && while true;do sleep 30; done;
```

and try to connect it on my pc like this

```
ssh tunnel@192.168.1.99 -p 2222 -i /mykeys/id_rsa
```

the **id_rsa** file is the **tunnel** user RSA key that generated on Server

Now I don't know what's wrong with my keys and permissions also I try the .pub key and it didn't work.
I'll appreciate that if somebody helps me to fix this

**UPDATE**

I try to regenerate the keys for tunnel user and try to connect with `-vvv` ( this run on **Termux** )

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.99 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.99 [192.168.1.99] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/myssh/id_rsa.pub type 0
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/myssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.99:2222 as 'tunnel'
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.1.99]:2222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.1.99]:2222
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:EyzYn+F+Awaoke1PPJfMECvyopckZG/s9S9hjsDn8hw
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.1.99]:2222
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.1.99]:2222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.1.99]:2222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.1.99]:2222
debug1: Host '[192.168.1.99]:2222' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/myssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:cbuXmcG8RZ6OVZJ757b1e9gbR8rLijiw/4FzJGSKvZw explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/myssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:cbuXmcG8RZ6OVZJ757b1e9gbR8rLijiw/4FzJGSKvZw explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
tunnel@192.168.1.99: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You have a very good question, but unfortunately you have posted it to the wrong StackExchange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank u